# Laravel 5.1 constrain and eager load multiple nested relations

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, eager-loading, eloquent

I have four models: OwnerCompany, Owner, User, and Role.

I want to get all OwnerCompanys eager loading their Owner and also eager loading *its* Users who have the Role with the *name* 'admin'.

```
OwnerCompany::with('owner.users')->whereHas('owner.users.roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'admin');
})->get();
```

This loads in the models but doesn't constrain the users, they are all loaded.

Comment: `OwnerCompany->Owner->User->Role` is that your table relationship

Comment: OwnerCompany is a pivot table between Owners and Companies, a User has a polymorphic relationship to either Owner or other models, and Users are also related to Roles through a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested . I think you are missing like or equal operator.

```
OwnerCompany::with('owner.users')->whereHas('owner.users.roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name','like','admin');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but 'like' or '=' is unnecessary as if it is omitted, it is implied that it is '='.

Answer (score 0):

I try this, if work then let me know. **not tested**

1).

```
OwnerCompany::with('owner.users.roles')->whereHas('owner', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('users', function($qr){
        $qr->whereHas('roles', function($q){
          $q->where('name', 'admin');
        });
    });
})->get();
```

OR

2).

```
OwnerCompany::with('owner.users.roles')->whereHas('owner.users.roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'admin');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but your second example is the same as what I wrote in the question (I don't need to load in the role model). As for your first, I need to only get back the users with the 'admin' role. When I map over the users I still see all of them.

Comment: are you checking `name = admin` in roles table or which table

Comment: In the roles table.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, it still pulls in all the users for a particular owner. Not just the ones who have the 'admin' role.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want each `OwnerCompany` object to contain the `Owner` object, which will contain "admins". I would do something like this.

```
$ownerCompany = OwnerCompany::all();

return $ownerCompany->each(function ($company) {
    $company->owner;
    $company->owner->users->each(function ($user) {
       return $user->hasRole('admin');
    });
});
```

and inside `User` class:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->role()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
         return $this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it right now, so If you have any trouble let me know.